# convert Json nested Object to a array of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

**

> Following is my response in json i like to convert it to a array of
>   object.**

```
{
    "1": {
        "addressName": "OFFICE",
        "building": "robust revolutionary copying CSS",
        "street": "703 Corwin Fords",
        "area": "2445 Kling Lake",

    },
    "2": {
        "addressName": "TEST LOC",
        "street": "3852 McDermott Manor",

    },
    "3": {
        "addressName": "HOME",
        "street": "818 Maeve Drives"

    }
}
```

Comment: This will help... `Object.values(data)`

Comment: See: [MDN: Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)